# Prevent Visual Studio from naming classes automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Silly question: I am looking through the options in VS for something that will allow me to prevent VS from automatically creating (or at least automatically naming) the starting files when you create a new project. When I create a new Windows Form application, for example, and I name both the project and the solution "ExampleForm," VS will create the project but add a default `Form1.cs` file. I would think it would at least name the first file after the project/solution.

Is there any setting for this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you may be looking to customize a project template. Take a look at this and reply if its what you are looking for and we may be able to help further - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I think you will have to define your own [Visual studio template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)